# Origin of the word addiction

Tags: etymology

I have heard the root of the word addiction is "to be enslaved" but what I'm seeing is "addico" "to be devoted". Is there any truth to "to be enslaved"?

Comment: See here: http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Daddico The Latin verb "addico" evidently had various meanings.

Comment: time-wise: to be sold --> to be enslaved --> to be devoted

Comment: When we say someone _is devoted to_ someone or something else, we mean that the devotion is personal and voluntary. That isn't what it used to mean when slaves were the subject; slaves were movable furniture, and you might devote some to field work and others to teach your children. They'd be "devoted" to their task like the lamp in the hallway is devoted to its.